# In Django, how to clear all the memcached keys and values?

Tags: python, django, caching, memcached

I don't want to restart the memcached server!

Comment: for what task it can be useful?

Comment: ...or if you memcached is serving several applications and you do not want to destroy everything at once!

Answer (score 42, accepted):

```
from django.core.cache import cache
cache._cache.flush_all()
```

Also see this ticket, it has a patch (that I haven't tested) to flush any type of cache backend: http://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/11503

Comment: For anyone who needs it, the cache lib is located in  django.core.cache.  So to run the command above, you need to import cache

    from django.core.cache import cache

Comment: I have `CACHE_MIDDLEWARE_ALIAS` pointing to a nondefault `memcached` cache but the command still tries to clear `default` and fails with `AttributeError: 'FileBasedCache' object has no attribute '_cache'`

Comment: These days, you can use `from django.core.cache import cache; cache.clear()`

Answer (score 2):

And an one-liner from console:

```
echo "from django.core.cache import cache; cache._cache.flush_all()" | ./manage.py shell [--settings=myapp.settings_live]
```

Answer (score 1):

An easiest and fastest way:

```
echo flush_all > /dev/tcp/localhost/11211
```